# Windows 7 Won't find Lexmark X4550

Tags: windows-7, lexmark-printer

I just got Lexmark X4550 wireless printer and want to have it installed on my laptop Windows 7 Beta. I have installed using Lexmark drivers and doing a "add a printer" device search. But when I tried to print a document i got an error message: "Communication not available. The printer cannot communicate with the computer...". This pinter used to work perfectly on my Windows XP Pro SP3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you honestly using Windows 7 **Beta**?

Comment: Windows 7 Beta expired nearly *two* years (August 1, 2009) ago...are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Does the printer show up in the list of “Printer and Faxes”? Is there any yellow exclaim marks when you check Device Manager? It sounds like a connection problem to me. Check the USB cable for any obvious damage. Firmly plug the square end of the USB cable into the USB port on the printer and the computer. If you have another USB cable, just try it too. You also need to confirm that you have downloaded and installed [the latest driver and firmware for your X4550](http://www.pcdriverhelper.com/).